# Check if connection exists when hosting resources on Dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropbox, carrierwave, dropbox-api

I store and read images on Dropbox with the help of the gems [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and [Carrierwave-Dropbox](https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox).

I'm not quite sure about the innerworks, how Carrierwave-Dropbox requests the Dropbox API. I would like to be able to check if there is connection exists, because right now I'm displaying the image like this:

```
<%= @user.profile_picture %>
```

and when fetching the image fails (e.g. offline on localhost), I get a `SocketError`.

**Update**

I cannot determine if the error occurs already in the controller or in the view, but it seems like it is in the view. Here's the message from the server (in the console):

```
ActionView::Template::Error (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known):
```

And in the browser the error page has the page title:

```
"Action Controller: Exception caught"
```

and the header in red in the browser window:

```
SocketError in Admin::Users#show
```

Comment: Any luck with this yet?

Comment: Thank you for the effort, and your solution looks really elegant, but of some *strange* reason `nil` is not set, so the `SocketError` persist...

Comment: Hmm... can you explain further? Is the error in the view or controller? And what do you mean when you say "`nil` is not set"? I'm confident that – with a few more details – I can get the supplied solution to work flawlessly... thoughts?

Comment: OK, I've updated the question with the error messages. What I meant with `nil` not being set is that even if I do a conditional in the view checking for `.present?` - the error persist.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than accessing the `profile_picture` attribute in the view (and thereby risking a `SocketError` exception), try moving the logic of handling the exception to your controller:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  begin
    @profile_picture = @user.profile_picture
  rescue SocketError => e      
    flash[:error] = "#{e}"
    @profile_picture = nil
  end
end
```

Then, in your view, you'll have access to both the `@user` object, as well as the `@profile_picture` (if it exists; otherwise, it's just `nil`):

```
# app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= @profile_picture %>
```